# Getting all POST from clone form elements

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms, clone

Here's my little problem:

I've this code http://jsfiddle.net/marcelo066/d7ehQ/light/ which I changed from [BrianGlaz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/830247/brian-glaz)'s original http://jsfiddle.net/B7bgN/10/ .It clones some part from a form. My question is: how can I get this cloned values using php to store it in a mysql database? Just for enlightenment, the code from my fiddle is a part from a bigger form, which is working. So i add this clone part, and I don't know how to get the cloned values from $_POST. Any ideas?

Comment: Please don't write tags in question titles...there's a special secret mechanism that already does that: tags, which you already used :)

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays on elements attributes names.

Alter the names of the elements so that instead of `name="myname"` and `name="myname2"`, `name="mayname3"` you have `name="myname[0]"` and `name="myname[1]"`, `name="myname[2]"`.

So that in the `$_POST` array you will have `$_POST['myname']` as an array will al original and cloned values and not `$_POST['myname']`,`$_POST['myname2']`,`$_POST['myname3']`.

Depending on the way you want to hanlde that you could also have original elements with names like `name="form[0][myname]"` and the others like `name="form[1][myname]"`, etc. At the end the original elements values are on `$_POST['form'][0]` and the others in `$_POST['form'][1]`, `$_POST['form'][2]`, etc.

I've made a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/regilero/6kd2L/1/
http://jsfiddle.net/regilero/6kd2L/1/

Where basically, appart from altering the way names are handled in the HTML part I 've altered

```
$(elem).attr('id', $(elem).attr('id') + newNum).attr('name', $(elem).attr('name')+ newNum);
```

To:

```
    var $elem = $(elem);
    $elem.attr('id', $elem.attr('id') + newNum);
    var ename = $elem.attr('name');
    if (ename) {
        $elem.attr('name',ename.replace('form[0]','form['+newNum+']'));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Name your form fields as array elements:

```
<select name="dormitorios_name[0]"... >
```

And for the clones make it respectively

```
<select name="dormitorios_name[1]"... >
...
<select name="dormitorios_name[2]"... >
```

Thus in you php code you can check for

```
$i = 0;
do {
    // save values
    $i++;
} while (isset( $_POST['dormitorios_name'][$i])
```